# Why does shopt fail when called from python?

Tags: python, linux, shopt

```
# shopt -s extglob

# python3
Python 3.4.0 (default, Sep  8 2015, 23:36:36) 
[GCC 4.7.3] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from subprocess import check_call
>>> check_call(['shopt', '-s', 'extglob'])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/subprocess.py", line 552, in check_call
    retcode = call(*popenargs, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/subprocess.py", line 533, in call
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/subprocess.py", line 848, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/subprocess.py", line 1446, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'shopt'
```

shopt doesn't appear to be in my path but bash does:

```
# echo $PATH | grep shopt
# whereis shopt
# whereis bash
bash: /bin/bash /etc/bash.bashrc /usr/share/man/man1/bash.1.gz
```

Comment: I guess it is not on your PATH?

Comment: `shopt` is a bash built-in,  not a command (i.e. an executable somewhere in the `PATH`).

Comment: `check_call(['/bin/bash', '-c', 'shopt -s extglob'])` works. but then the shell quits and the settings are lost...

Comment: PROTIP: `which shopt` would have tipped you off

Comment: What are you trying to do? Why are you trying to programmatically set shell options? We may be able to help, but I'm guessing what's posted so far is not your real question.

Comment: I'm trying to rm all but two files in a directory but those two files MUST stay in directory (can't copy mv them out then back in).  I can copy them out but there could be an issue with that too.  Found another way but unfortunately don't know what to do about this not being in my path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to "*rm all but two files in a directory*", you can do that directly from Python without invoking a shell. This program removes all of the files in `/tmp/r`, except for two that I want to keep.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import os

keepers = ['safe', 'also_safe.txt']
os.chdir('/tmp/r')

for filename in os.listdir('.'):
    if filename not in keepers:
        print('Removing %s' % (filename,))
        os.remove(filename)
```

And, for fun, here is a combined module and script that provide the same functionality:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import os
import argparse
import sys

def safe_remove(dirs, exclude, verbose, dry_run):
    for directory in dirs:
        if verbose or dry_run:
            print("Checking directory '%s'" % (directory,))
        for filename in os.listdir(directory):
            if filename not in exclude:
                filename = os.path.join(directory, filename)
                if verbose or dry_run:
                    print('rm %s'%filename)
                if not dry_run:
                    os.remove(filename)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Remove files, with exceptions')
    parser.add_argument('-x', '--exclude',
                        metavar='FILE',
                        default=[],
                        nargs='+',
                        help='files to exclude')
    parser.add_argument('dirs',
                        metavar='DIR',
                        nargs='+',
                        help='directories to clean')
    parser.add_argument('-v', '--verbose',
                        action='store_true',
                        help='Print actions')
    parser.add_argument('-n', '--dry-run',
                        action='store_true',
                        help='Print, but do not perform, actions')
    args = parser.parse_args()
    safe_remove(**vars(args))
```